# SQL Workbench and WbExport

Tags: camelcasing, sql-workbench-j

I've searched high and low and can't seem to find a solution. I've got a query that runs and then does the WbExport function once complete. This is exporting to an .xls file. However, it's exporting as all lower case for the header. The table headers are this way as well. Recreating the table as camel case doesn't fix it because the table headers still remain as all lower case. The exported file needs to have camel case. Is there any way for me to fix this without correcting it manually every time?

Comment: The column headers in the Excel file are taken "as is" from the column names of the query. If your database always returns them in lower case (e.g. Postgres), then the names will be in lowercase in Excel as well. In Postgres (or Oracle) you would need to use double quotes to preserve the exact writing, e.g. `select some_column as "SomeColumn"

Comment: This doesn't work. It is an Oracle database but it appears the DB admin purposely setup the database to create tables using only lowercase regardless of how you create the table. So now I've got to find another way to do a daily export out of SQL workbench where the headers will be formatted correctly.

Comment: SQL Workbench uses the column names as returned by the JDBC driver. There is no way in Oracle to configure it to convert all columns into lower case, so the table was most definitely created using quoted identifiers e.g. `create table "foo" ("id" number, "some_column" varchar(20))` - the only way around that is to use quoted identifiers in the query that is used for the export `select "some_column" as "SomeColumn" ...`